# How to access new data in Django UpdateView

Tags: django, forms, view

I wanted to display in success_message new data, changed in my generic UpdateView.
And i dunno how to access those data from form.

Everything is like super standard, code look like that:

```
class ProductOneUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = ProductOne
    fields = ['quantity']
    success_message = ................
```

And i want new quantity, changed by user shown in this success_message.
Looking forward for yours answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> The **cleaned data from the form** is available for **string interpolation** using the `%(field_name)s` syntax.

So if these are form fields, you can write a message like:

```
class ProductOneUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = ProductOne
    fields = ['quantity']
    success_message = 'The quantity is updated to %(quantity)s'
```

For more advanced processing of success messages, you can override the [**`get_success_message`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.views.SuccessMessageMixin.get_success_message), this passes the `cleaned_data` as parameter, and you can access the (updated) object through `self.object`:

```
class ProductOneUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = ProductOne
    fields = ['quantity']
    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return 'The quantity of {} is updated to {}'.format(
            self.object,
            self.cleaned_data['quantity']
        )
```